# action='action-page' and target='_blank' in a form tag

Tags: javascript, html, windows, forms, performance

What's the difference between  **action='action-page' and  target='_blank'** in a form tag?

Do they perform the same function?

Comment: It might by worthwhile familiarizing yourself with the [HELP] and [TOUR]. From there you'll see that some research is expected before asking your question. MDN is a good source of documentation. See the attributes section of the [form element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) if you still have questions after that, please rephrase your question in reference to that.

Answer (score 1):

`Action` attributes specifies where to take a user or form data after submitting the form and `target=_blank` specifies that a new window or tab will be opened after submitting the form

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at how a `form` tag works.

In general. a `form` tag sends data to a web server to to do something via an http request. There are 3 important attributes to consider

1. `action` : this is the **URL of the server resource** that is going to process the request
2. `method` : generally GET or POST, this set's **how** the request will be made using HTTP request verbs (GET/POST etc)
3. `target` : the **window or tab** where the action URL (generally left out to process in the current window or tab.

For more info on these and other form attributes see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Answer (score 0):

No They are different
The `action` attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted.
Whereas,
a `target="_blank"` Open in New Browser Tab (or Window) The target attribute specifies where the linked document will open when the link is clicked. The default is the current window. If `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 0):

ok so *action-page* is a sort of "attribute, variable or function" name meaning form action will run the block of code specific to *action-page* the *target_blank* just makes another page open and the function or attribute code is run on the new page.

Answer (score 0):

No both are not the same. they're a bit different.

`Action`="form-data-submit.php" means the destination of the form when submit the form
`Target = "_blank"` means to telling the form to be submit by opening a new tab.

The **action attribute means where the form will go after submittin**g and if you add the **target(_blank) attribute in the form then the form will go to a new tab** with its respected URL(given to action attribute).